# RabbitMQ on .NetCore

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

From the documentations I read that `RabbitMQ 4.X` series supported in `.NetCore`.

I am trying to add the `RabbitMQ Client` from the Nuget and it fails.

I tried `.Net Core 1.0/1.1` , with `RabbitMQ Client` 4.0.0 - 4.1.3.

I keep getting an error:

```
Unable to resolve `...` for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.
```

Am I missing something?

**Edit CS proj**

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DotNetstandard1\DotNetstandard1.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Nuget complete error**

```
Install-Package : Unable to resolve 'c:\users\cynet\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\CoreApp1\DotNetstandard1\DotNetstandard1.csproj' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package RabbitMQ.Client -Version 4.1.3
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'CoreApp1'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package RabbitMQ.Client -Version 4.1.3
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: Can you share your `.csproj` ? What version of VS are you using? Also the complete error message from nuget

Comment: @Cemre added the csproj, VS2017

Comment: Is `DotNestandard1` a different project ? If so, what's its framework ?

Comment: @Cemre yup, just noticed it myself, thats the issue, DotNestandard1 is a refferenced project of .netstandard 1.4, thats why it failed

Comment: Glad that you found it :)

Comment: Thanks for the help